# Logic app can't be triggered for Nested SharePoint folders

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

My requirements is *whenever a files is created or modified inside the sharepoint folder*, I've to do some logic.

This is what it looks like.

[image]

The problem is I've many nested folder inside the `Shared Documents`, my logic app can only be executed if i created or modify the files inside the `Shared Documents`, but not on the files which i created/modified inside the nested folders.

E.g,

> Shared Document
>       -> Folder1
>       -> Folder2

Here my logic app triggered only on shared documents and not on `Folder1` or `Folder2`

Comment: As far as I know, it is caused by design but not a problem.

Comment: @HuryShen Is there any workaround for that ?Because my folders are going to increase day by day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, logic app doesn't support this feature now and I don't think exist a good workaround which can help us to implement this requirement because this involves multiple files/folders in multiple levels in the folder which you specified.

Maybe you can vote up for this feature on this [feedback page](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/suggestions/39863188-sharepoint-trigger-for-file-created-or-modified-in) to suggest Microsoft about this feature.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue and I managed to fix it very easy. There is an activity, called "When a file is created or modified (properties only)". It can listen to subfolders also. Then, if you need file content you can get it using the properties returned by this trigger with the "Get content activity"